# highlight an arabic word in a string with diacritics Android

Tags: java, android, string, mobile, arabic

I want to highlight a searched word in a string that contains diacritics,
the user search for a word example "محمد" so I've implemented a function that removes the diacritics from the string and return the index of the searched word in the string
String with diacritics : حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ
String without diacritics : حدثنا محمد   here the start index of the word is 6
but the problem is that the index of the searched word is not the same in the content with diacritics

this is the method that retrieve the index of the searched word and apply highlights

```
        String normalizedSearchText = removeDiacritics(searchText.toLowerCase().trim());
        String normalizedContent = removeDiacritics(content.toLowerCase().trim());

        int startIndex = normalizedContent.indexOf(normalizedSearchText);

        if (startIndex != -1) {
            Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(content);
            int endIndex = startIndex + searchText.length();

            // Customize the background color of the matched text
            BackgroundColorSpan backgroundColorSpan = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);
            spannable.setSpan(backgroundColorSpan, startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            // Apply the Spannable to the TextView
            binding.tvContent.setText(spannable);
```

this is the output
[the searched word is the second word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAeVs.jpg)

Comment: *String with diacritics : حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ* Which are the "diacritics" in that?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is here. If you delete characters (tashkil in this case), you need to keep track of where the characters you delete were, and create a mapping of all the indices so you can line up the highlighting. Your code doesn't seem to do that. (It's also unclear why you're calling `toLowerCase()`. What do you expect that to do on Arabic text?) I would expect the same problems if you run this on accented European text, depending on how it happens to be encoded.

Comment: @g00se See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_diacritics for an explanation of Arabic diacritics. They're more complex than European diacritics, but generally people mean the tashkil marks, and particularly the harakat marks. In the above text, they are fatah (ـَ), dammah (ـُ), and shaddah (ـّ). (Shaddah is not harakat, but it is tashkil.) While different in usage, they have a lot in common with European diacritics like acute accent and umlaut, in that they indicate pronunciation without necessarily changing the letter (but, like European diacritics, "it depends").